# Why PostGIS slower than MySQL in searching spatial data?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, postgis, spatial

I heard that PostGIS is optimized for searching geographic data like geometry, polygraph.. etc.
so I tested it to figure out how much faster it is than MySQL.

first, this is the query currently used for searching nearby places from a given latitude and longitude in MySQL.

```
select * from place where mbrcontains(ST_LINESTRINGFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(127.0214 37.4777, 126.9444 37.4166)'), coord)
```

it takes 30 milliseconds on average.

And these queries are tested for the same purpose in PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension.
coord column is geography type and coord2 column is geometry type, two columns have GIST index.

```
1. select * from place
where coord2 && st_setsrid(st_makebox2d(ST_point(127.0214, 37.4777), ST_Point(126.9444, 37.4166)), 4326);

2. select * from place
where st_dwithin('SRID=4326;POINT(126.9829371 37.4472168)'::geography, coord, 1000);

3. select * from place
where 'LINESTRING(127.0214 37.4777, 126.9444 37.4166)'::geometry ~ coord2
```

These take at least 150 milliseconds and 250 milliseconds on average.

as a result, rather, MySQL is at least about five times faster than PostGIS.

specs of database servers are same and rows of tested data is about 40000.
version of MySQL is 5.7.33, PostgreSQL is 14.5

Is this a normal result?

### Query Plans each queries

```
1. "Bitmap Heap Scan on place  (cost=10.32..622.30 rows=264 width=176) (actual time=0.083..0.117 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (coord2 && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240EA95B20C71BC5F404CA60A4625BD42409A081B9E5EC15F404CA60A4625BD42409A081B9E5EC15F40BEC1172653B54240EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240'::geometry)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=12"
"  Buffers: shared hit=20"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on coord2_index  (cost=0.00..10.26 rows=264 width=0) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=84 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (coord2 && '0103000020E61000000100000005000000EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240EA95B20C71BC5F404CA60A4625BD42409A081B9E5EC15F404CA60A4625BD42409A081B9E5EC15F40BEC1172653B54240EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240'::geometry)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=8"
"Planning Time: 0.134 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.147 ms"

2. "Bitmap Heap Scan on place  (cost=4.53..491.25 rows=4 width=176) (actual time=0.067..0.130 rows=11 loops=1)"
"  Filter: st_dwithin('0101000020E61000009BA10271E8BE5F40631C6D663EB94240'::geography, coord, '2000'::double precision, true)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 16"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=5"
"  Buffers: shared hit=12"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on coord_index  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=17 width=0) (actual time=0.055..0.056 rows=27 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (coord && _st_expand('0101000020E61000009BA10271E8BE5F40631C6D663EB94240'::geography, '2000'::double precision))"
"        Buffers: shared hit=7"
"Planning Time: 0.116 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.150 ms"

3. "Bitmap Heap Scan on place  (cost=4.59..141.82 rows=40 width=176) (actual time=0.133..0.167 rows=84 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ('0102000000020000009A081B9E5EC15F404CA60A4625BD4240EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240'::geometry ~ coord2)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=12"
"  Buffers: shared hit=20"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on coord2_index  (cost=0.00..4.58 rows=40 width=0) (actual time=0.126..0.126 rows=84 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (coord2 @ '0102000000020000009A081B9E5EC15F404CA60A4625BD4240EA95B20C71BC5F40BEC1172653B54240'::geometry)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=8"
"Planning Time: 0.060 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.199 ms"
```

- PostgreSQL 14.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit"
- POSTGIS=""3.1.7 aafe1ff"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""140"" GEOS=""3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2"" PROJ=""8.0.1"" LIBXML=""2.9.1"" LIBJSON=""0.15"" LIBPROTOBUF=""1.3.2"" WAGYU=""0.5.0 (Internal)"""

Comment: No `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, no answer.

Comment: Output of `select version(), postgis_full_version();` and DDLs for the test tables and indices would be helpful as well (thanks for attaching the query plan already). I know it's a bit much, but there are too many ways these setups can be different to provide a good answer. As to benchmarking, use [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) to get more test samples and generate more data (`generate_series()` to multiply your data set and `ST_Translate()` combined with `random()` to shift around), to see how it scales. You're currently judging based on a very small sample.

Comment: Those are microseconds, not milliseconds. 0.201 ms is 201 microseconds, point-two-zero-one of a millisecond.

Comment: `0.150ms` is not "150ms" - it's just slightly longer than **a tenth** of a millisecond. If you really do measure 150ms in your application (or SQL client) the difference of 149.85ms is caused by network latency and/or processing time in your application or SQL client

Comment: omg.. thanks a lot! i measure those execution time in pgAdmin 4 and python scripts. so, i think i need to find out how to reduce the latency time.

Comment: @hwanlee - "latency" could be dominated by the time it takes to get to the server.  Are the client and server on the same computer?  If not, how long does `SELECT 1` take?

Comment: @RickJames
No, The client and server are not on the same computer. ```select 1``` takes 9.93ms in MySQL and 21.77ms in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That tells me that they are geographically quite far apart.  And, since every query will add 10ms to 22ms, that network delay can slow things down.  100 simple queries would take a second or more.  However, the slowlog won't include that 10ms delay.

Comment: @RickJames But, i used RDS and EC2 for this test in the same region. i haven't figured out why the network latency of PostgreSQL is about twice higher than MySQL yet.

Comment: @hwanlee - and it is not quite 2x; more like 2.2x.  Try some other queries.  Perhaps `SELECT NOW()` or `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1`.  Run each twice.  _Maybe_ the 2.2 was a fluke and it is a steady 2.0 -- indicating that Postgres is doing an extra query??

Comment: And...  MySQL has a "general log", which can capture all the queries; does Postres have a similar log?

Comment: @RickJames i tested `select now()` in MySQL and PostgreSQL. it takes first 11.58ms and next 7.3566ms in MySQL, and first 57.625ms and next 21.2543ms in PostgreSQL.

Comment: and i set the logger of PostgreSQL to collect all queries, but I couldn't find any additional queries that were executed.

Comment: @hwanlee - milliseconds vs microseconds again??

Comment: @RickJames I used this python script in order to measure the latency.
`start = time()
**DB QUERY EXECUTE**
print((time() - start) * 1000)`

so, definitely milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the comments, to close the thread with an answer:

1. `"Execution Time: 0.147 ms"` reads *zero point one four seven* ***of a millisecond***, which is 147 **micro**seconds.
2. Reproducibility/consistency: if you run the test once and one query runs better, it still can be worse the next time you run it. Use [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) to run your tests multiple times over and over, to let the noise average out.
3. Sample size: you're working on a table with less than a 100 rows, so the differences in execution times are close to noise. You can spawn some more samples by duplicating and shifting your data round. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kzzRxkRQ):

   ```sql
   create table place (id serial primary key, coord2 geometry(Point,4326));
   insert into place (coord2) 
   values ('SRID=4326;POINT(126.9829371 37.4472168)'::geometry);

   --1000000 test records 
   --in random places within 30 degrees distance from sample point
   create table tests as 
   select tests.test_case_id,
          repeat(gen_random_uuid()::text,30) as a_heavy_column,
          ST_Translate(coord2, random()*60 -30, random()*60 -30) as test_geom
   from place p join generate_series(1,1e6,1) tests(test_case_id) on true;

   explain analyze 
   select *
   from tests
   where st_dwithin('SRID=4326;POINT(126.9829371 37.4472168)'::geometry,
                    test_geom,
                    5);
   ```

   This also lets you see how things scale. A query running 1 second is "twice as fast" as one running 2 seconds, but it might no longer be the case when you run against a bigger sample - the difference can become negligible or even go the other way, if the second query scales better.
4. Controlled environment (know what you're measuring): even if the platform is the same, it's a challenge to set up config equivalents for the two different RDBMS, to be sure they are given the same level of access to the platform resources. Other activity on the platform needs to be restricted, other traffic on the DBs needs to be restricted, tests should run in-db or at least locally to eliminate latency.